# Linq: Where count greater than value

Tags: linq

I have a linq query which accepts a list of date and port combinations. This query has to return data from a table, CruiseCalendar, where these combinations are found, but only when the count is greater than one. I cant work out the groupby and count syntax. var shipRendezvous is where I'm stuck.

```
        var dateAndPort = (from r in context.CruiseCalendar
                        where r.ShipId == shipId
                        && r.CruiseDayDate >= dateRange.First
                        && r.CruiseDayDate <= dateRange.Last
                        select new DateAndPort
                        {
                            Date = r.CruiseDayDate,
                            PortId = r.PortId
                        });

        var shipRendezvous = (from r in context.CruiseCalendar
                              where (dateAndPort.Any(d => d.Date == r.CruiseDayDate
                              && d.PortId == r.PortId))
                              orderby r.CruiseDayDate // (Added since first posting)
                              select r).ToList();
```

regards, Guy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are filterting for every set which matches any of the results of `dateAndPort` and then want to group it by itsself to get a count. Of the grouping results you only want those resultsets, which occur more then once.

```
var shipRendezvous = (from r in context.CruiseCalendar
                      where (dateAndPort.Any(d => d.Date == r.CruiseDayDate
                      && d.PortId == r.PortId))
                      select r)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.CruiseDayDate) //Groups by every combination
                     .Where(x => x.Count() > 1) //Where Key count is greater 1
                     .ToList();
```

Based on your comment, you want to flatten the list again. To do so, use `SelectMany()`:

```
var shipRendezvous = (from r in context.CruiseCalendar
                      where (dateAndPort.Any(d => d.Date == r.CruiseDayDate
                      && d.PortId == r.PortId))
                      select r)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.CruiseDayDate) //Groups by every combination
                     .Where(x => x.Count() > 1) //Where Key count is greater 1
                     .SelectMany(x => x)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Serv, Thanks. Almost there. Original query had erroneous omission (apologies, see update). GroupBy(x => x) returned 0 records. Changed to .GroupBy(x => x.CruiseDayDate). This now returns the desired number of results, but not as list of CruiseCalendar results but List <IGrouping><System.DateTime.CruiseDayDate>. How do I get it to return the former?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the additional solution to "flatten" your results.

Comment: Thanks Serv, I've give marked the answer as good (another issue has turned up, but I think its related to something else).regards, Guy

Comment: Well, then fire up another question, if you can't solve it by yourself.